# When does a user get notified for a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, notifications

If a comment is addressed to me (explicitly via @ or implicitly if added to one of my questions or answers), I get notified in the inbox at the top of the page. If I don't respond (or look there) for some time, I get an email.

What is the timing for both kind of messages? Is there a grace period?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you don't want that, go to [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2932052/wolf), switch to the **Edit Profile & Settings** tab, select **Preferences** from the sidebar and untick (or alter the frequency for - it's either every three hours, daily or weekly) *"Email me my unread inbox messages"* in the **Emails** section.

---

Notifications appear at the top of the screen in real time, so long as your browser supports WebSocket, see:

- https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/new-global-inbox; and
- [New Feature: real time updates to questions, answers, and inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125677/248731)

Comment: Ok thanks so far. But when does the SO-internal inbox message appear? Instantly or after some kind of "grace period"?

Comment: I clarified the question, do you have an answer for remaining part?

Comment: If by "SO-internal" you mean the red flag at the top of the page; instantly.

Comment: Yes, I mean the read flag (or increment to the number there). Is this *instantly* solid knowledge (or just a guess?) - could you add this detail into your answer? ...and thanks for improving my question :-)

Comment: @Wolf see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/new-global-inbox/, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox - it's real-time as long as your browser can use websockets.

Comment: Please add that _to the answer_, Jon. Comments are transient.