# Why was the accepted answer to my question deleted and why wasn't I notified?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I've just found out that the answer I accepted to [a question I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54019747/how-to-automate-saving-webpages) no longer appears. Two questions:

- Why has this happened?
- I get an e-mail when someone posts an answer or a comment to a question I've asked. Shouldn't I likewise be told when an answer has been deleted, or better yet, when an answer is being considered for deletion so I can weigh in on the decision?

Edit: In addition to the accepted answer, I also posted my own answer with more details. My answer referred to the accepted answer. I now see that someone commented on my answer, saying that there is no accepted answer. But I didn't get an e-mail about that comment. Why not?

Comment: The answer was deleted by a moderator 11 months ago. The account has been destroyed - I'm guessing for spamming, based on the context

Comment: Would someone like to explain what's so bad about my question that it's been downvoted twice within ten minutes of being posted?

Comment: People disagree with your foundational premise, namely that email notifications should be provided when answers are deleted and/or that you should be able to weigh in on moderation decisions regarding deletion of spam. Disagreement is a common reason to downvote on Meta. It doesn't mean that there's anything wrong with the question itself.

Comment: Okay. How about the added question about why I wasn't notified about the comment on my question?

Comment: I'm not really sure about that. Personally, I would be apoplectic if I got email notifications about everything that happened on this site. I currently have nearly 600 notifications in my on-site inbox. If you care about what goes on here, it stands to reason that you would log in and check. Anyway, comments aren't considered important on this site, so it stands to reason that you would not be notified via email about them.

Comment: So, actually, you *can* opt in to being notified via email about unread comments. See here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295352/when-does-a-user-get-notified-for-a-comment. There's a checkbox, "Email me my unread inbox messages" in [the "Emails" section of your profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/5803910).

Comment: Now someone has deleted that comment on my answer.

Comment: Yes. It wasn't a useful comment anyway, and especially not now that you've already seen it.

Comment: I just checked my profile, "Settings > Edit email settings > Inbox". It is set to "3 hrs". I guess it's a glitch that I didn't get that particular notification. (I'm not nearly as active here as you are, so I appreciate knowing when something relevant has happened here.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are never notified of "negative" actions. This includes the deletion of a post. There's nothing that you can or should do about a post having been deleted, so notification does not make sense.

Moderators do not delete answers capriciously, so you can assume that there is a good reason for doing so. [That particular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54025412) was deleted as part of a major spam cleanup. It was posted by a fraudulent account that had only ever contributed content promoting their own products without any disclosure, [against our rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Comment: "you can assume that there is a good reason": I don't assume mods are infallible. That answer was useful enough that I accepted it and expanded on it in my own answer. My answer lacks context without the accepted answer. Would it be acceptable for me to edit my answer with a link to the accepted answer on Archive.org (https://web.archive.org/web/20190124011152/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54019747/how-to-automate-saving-webpages)?

Comment: Yes, that would be acceptable. Or you can just edit the relevant information and/or links from that post directly into yours, without needing to point to an off-site resource.

Comment: I have made the edit. Would you please check it and let me know if it's acceptable, so I don't get surprised later to find that it's been deemed offensive and removed?

Comment: @NewSites Just so you know, Archive.org sets all links to nofollow, so if you’re looking for Google juice on the links from the deleted answer, linking to archive.org won’t help you (I’m not saying you are, just giving you a heads up in case).

Comment: Nope, no interest in Google juice. I just want my answer to make sense to people who read it.

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with the entire email premise of the question, but I do think that if I accept an answer and it is later altered or deleted, it would be nice to get a comment notification, comparable to when my post is edited.

Accepting an answer configures a dependency, possible subsequent violations of which deserve notification. If I accept an answer and the answerer later, say, replaces it with garbage, that reflects on me and ill serves the public.  If I were notified, I could retract or shift my acceptance. As things are, I might never discover the problem.

(Given the current tattered functionality of the site, however, I do not feel strongly enough about this to propose it as a new feature at this time.)

Comment: The site now has the "follow" feature, would allow you to be notified of edits to the answer you are concerned with. It does not, however, notify about deletion.